# Access to Azure Active Directory Subscription - My Role: Unknown

Tags: azure-active-directory

In portal.azure.com I have two subscriptions.

One of them is the subscription named "Access to Azure Active Directory". As far as I can understand, this subscription was created automatically via the Office 365 subscription I have.

My profile is a Global Administrator. However, I cannot access "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription as a Global Administrator or with Global Administrator rights. More specifically, when I view "My permissions" in "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription, it says "You are an administrator on the subscription".

But, when for example I try to view "Activity log" or "Access control (IAM)" in "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription, it says "DisallowedOperation: The current subscription type is not permitted to perform operations on any provider namespace. Please use a different subscription."

So, how is it possible to be an administrator on "Access to Azure Active Directory" subscription and also not able to do any action as an administrator?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards, Nick

Comment: You can try to register the resource providers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types

Answer (score 0):

Usually, an Office 365 subscription includes a free subscription to Azure AD so that you can integrate Office 365 with Azure AD if you want to sync passwords or set up single sign-on with your on-premises environment. You could refer to this: [Azure integration with Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/azure-integration?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fazure-integration-with-office-365-a5efce5d-9c9c-4190-b61b-fd273c1d425f). Before you can manage your Office 365 Apps in Azure AD, you need to Register your free Azure Active Directory subscription and Turning Integrated Apps on or off. Please refer to this: Integrated Apps and [Azure AD for Office 365 administrators](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/access-to-azure-active-directory-subscriptions/c85784bc-1479-410f-8500-be64600eccc4).